# Ping to avahi device does not work all the time

Tags: networking, kubuntu, hostname, nas, avahi

I just added a NAS to my home network and gave it the hostname `mynas`. I tried to access the NAS from Kubuntu 20.04 (especially via Samba). It works fine when using plain hostname, but it fails when using "mynas.local".

I.e. `ping mynas` works fine, `ping mynas.local` does not.

I understand that `.local` names are resolved using Avahi/Zeroconf (Bonjour). So I run `avahi-browse -at` which properly locates the NAS. Immediately after that, `ping mynas.local` works fine – for a minute. Then it stops working until the next `avahi-browse -at`.

Is this a Kubuntu or a NAS problem? What can I do to permanently enable avahi name resolution?

Please note that the edits below were checked using a new Kubuntu 21.10 installation.

Edit: Content of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Edit2: `$ avahi-browse -at`

```
+ enp5s0 IPv6 mynas                    Web-Angebot          local
+ enp5s0 IPv6 mynas                    Microsoft Windows Network local
+ enp5s0 IPv6 mynas                    Device Info          local
+ enp5s0 IPv4 mynas                    Web-Angebot          local
+ enp5s0 IPv4 mynas                    Microsoft Windows Network local
+ enp5s0 IPv4 mynas                    Device Info          local
```

Edit3: `$ systemctl status avahi-daemon.service`

```
avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-12-30 23:27:10 CET; 2h 42min ago
TriggeredBy: avahi-daemon.socket
   Main PID: 46832 (avahi-daemon)
     Status: "avahi-daemon 0.8 starting up."
```

BTW the error I get on ping to mynas.local is "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Comment: It is a user problem ... you probably haven't defined mynas.local anywhere.

Comment: So I have to explictely choose between mynas and mynas.local as a hostname? Well, if I choose "mynas" how can mynas.local ever work?

Comment: I guess that you have defined mynas in `/etc/hosts` as `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  mynas`. Add mysql.local kike this `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   mynas mynas.local`. If you have defined the host-name in other ways (like in DNS) there are similar ways to define host-name aliases.

Comment: Didn't do anything like that. I only set the name of the NAS in two places: The hostname and the domain name. There is a description of the domain name that says "If you set a NetBIOS name like `synologynas` you will be able to access the device in your local network using a URL like `https://synologynas.local`". This implies that I do not need to add the `.local` explicitly.

Comment: @Silicomancer seems alright, when the `ping` fails before running `avahi-browse` , check if avahi daemon is running fine, using `systemctl status avahi-daemon.service`

Comment: @Silicomancer If you are using IPv6 then, set `mdns6_minimal`(for IPv6-only) or `mdns_minimal` (for mixed IPv4 & IPv6). If you have multiple or dual interfaces that have common net for both devices, set avahi to work on only one `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` using `allow-interfaces=` or `deny-interfaces=` settings see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/avahi-daemon.conf.5.html . Make sure you have rebooted both machines after changing settings. Btw, they should be in same subnet (not router or subnet masking) that block some connections or firewall.